# Manipulation events not triggering on Templated Control [UWP]

Tags: xaml, uwp, custom-controls, uwp-xaml, template-control

I am trying to implement a custom control (Templated Control) for a UWP application for transforming shapes (mostly Rectangle types). Custom control will be implemented in a UWP class library and reference to the main project. What I want to achieve is draw the custom control around another basic shape (eg: Rectangle) and transform the shape according to the manipulations done on the custom control.

I am trying to implement the control with manipulation events (ManipulationDelta, ManipulationCompleted).

I was able to achieve a similar behavior using pointer related events(PointerPressed, PointerMoved, PointerReleased) but it is not very smooth & I want to integrate this control with other applications easily.

Please find the [sample source code here](https://github.com/sparxy3d/rectangle_manipulation).

When I try to move the control the manipulation events are not firing, and I cannot figure out the reason.

I started to work on UWP applications recently and any help on this matter is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, there are several removing codes in `PointPressed` event, such as `“RootCanvas.Children.Remove()”`. When you move the control, the PointPressed event is triggered, the previous generated rectangle named resizableRectV2 is deleted. So the `resizableRectV2.ManipulationCompleted` event will not be triggered.

In addition, I suggest that you don’t create two completely overlapping rectangles, which makes you confused.

**Update:**

SpeakerView.xaml.cs:

```
RootCanvas.Children.Remove(RootCanvas.Children.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(ResizableRectangle)).FirstOrDefault());
```

I mean that you could delete the above code in OnPointerPressed event.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to help me with this. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I have updated the answer, please try it.